# HtmlHelper accessing parent object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, reflection, html-helper, expression-trees

Suppose I am writing a strongly typed HtmlHelper extension to be called from my view as:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Foo.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.MyFormat(m => m.Foo[i].Bar);
}
```

Suppose I want to access other properties of Foo[i] in my helper.  I know I can do this by writing code like:

```
    @Html.MyFormat(m => m.Foo[i].Bar, m => m.Foo[i]);
```

But is there a less verbose way?  I know how to use the System.Linq.Expressions classes to get a MethodCallExpression equivalent to 'm.Foo[i]' from 'm => m.Foo[i].Bar' but can't figure out how to actually access the object (without using .Compile to create a new lambda).

Comment: at least I would write the MyFormat function in this way: @Html.MyFormat(m => m.Foo[i], f => f.Bar);

Comment: found something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265556/expressions-to-property-path

Comment: Why is calling `Compile()` an issue?